# Parsing entities of text message in telegram bot sent BY the user

Tags: python, telegram, telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot

I am writing a telegram bot that needs to know how the text has been stylized by the user (bold, italicized, strikethrough, spoiler, etc.). But it is not clear to me how this can be done or if it is even possible. I am using python and the `python-telegram-bot` package. I have figured out how to send stylized messages by having the Dispatcher parse the message being sent to the user in markdown. But how can I do the same thing receiving messages?

To make a very simple example, let's take this bot that just has a "start" command.

```
def start_command(update, context):
    update.message.reply_text(context.args) # reply message back to the user

def main():
    defaults = Defaults(parse_mode='MarkdownV2')

    updater = Updater(API_KEY, use_context=True, defaults=defaults)
    dp = updater.dispatcher

    dp.add_handler(CommandHandler("start", start_command))

    updater.start_polling(0)
    updater.idle()
```

How can I make it such that it knows the argument was bolded, italicized, etc. by the user?

To make it clear, I want to be able to distinguish between:

- /start hello
- /start **hello**
- /start *hello*
- ...

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your use case, there several things that you can use one of the following:

- [`Message.entities`](https://python-telegram-bot.readthedocs.io/en/stable/telegram.message.html#telegram.Message.entities) is a list of [`MessageEntity`](https://python-telegram-bot.readthedocs.io/en/stable/telegram.messageentity.html) objects that tell you how the text is formatted. However, since a `MessageEntity` only contains info on the offset and length, it's a bit tricky to get the text that's formatted by the entity.
- PTB offers the convenience methods [`Message.parse_entity`](https://python-telegram-bot.readthedocs.io/en/stable/telegram.message.html#telegram.Message.parse_entity) and [`Message.parse_entities`](https://python-telegram-bot.readthedocs.io/en/stable/telegram.message.html#telegram.Message.parse_entities). The first accepts one of the elements of `Message.entities` and returns the text covered by that entity. The second returns a dictionary, where the keys are the elements of `Message.enities` and the values are the corresponding return values of `Message.parse_entity`.
- Finally [`Message.text_html`](https://python-telegram-bot.readthedocs.io/en/stable/telegram.message.html#telegram.Message.text_html) and [`Message.text_markdown_v2`](https://python-telegram-bot.readthedocs.io/en/stable/telegram.message.html#telegram.Message.text_markdown_v2) are convenience properties that give you the text with the corresponding markup inserted. E.g. `message.reply_html(message.text_html)` will send a message that's formatted exactly like `message`.

---

Disclaimer: I'm currently the maintainer of `python-telegram-bot`.

Answer (score 1):

The method [*getUpdates*](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#getting-updates) used to retrieve messages sent from users allows you to gather all of the mentioned entities inside of a user message.

Per each ***Update*** object containing a ***Message*** object you could find easily the related entities like you're trying to do.

Following the official [Telegram's Message object representation](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#message), each Message object has a field named *entities* which is an array of ***[MessageEntity](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#messageentity)***.

Let's assume that I sent a text message like so:
"plain text **bold text** *italic text*"

The Update object will be structured as:

```
{
"message": {
    "message_id": 181,
    "from": {
        "id": user_id,
        "is_bot": false,
        "first_name": "first_name",
        "username": "username",
        "language_code": "en"
    },
    "chat": {
        "id": user_id,
        "first_name": "first_name",
        "username": "username",
        "type": "private"
    },
    "date": 1642080625,
    "text": "plain text bold text italic text",
    "entities": [{
        "offset": 11,
        "length": 10,
        "type": "bold"
    },  {
        "offset": 21,
        "length": 11,
        "type": "italic"
    }]
}
```

You could associate really easily per each text piece its own entity thanks to the **offset**, the **length** of this entity and its **type**.

In our case, we could understand that we have a **10 characters** bold entity starting **from the 11th characters** of the entire message.